# Как сделать такое расположение блоков на Bootstrap?

Tags: css, html5, bootstrap

Нужно, чтобы блоки на странице располагались вот так для десктопа, планшета и телефона соответственно. Для десктопа малые блоки - `.col-lg-3`, большой - `.col-lg-6`
[image: десктоп]
[image: планшет]
[image: телефон]

Расположением последних легко управлять, используя стандартные бутстраповские `flex` и `order`. А вот как быть с десктопной версией?

Флексбокс в данном случае сразу отпадает, т. к. все блоки там переносятся на следующий ряд. Была мысль организовать всё это на флоатах, задав `.row` блочное отображение на десктопах, но они тоже что-то закапризничали.

Хотелось бы узнать, как можно решить эту проблему без использования JS (да и с использованием тоже задача нетривиальная).

Comment: а в чем проблема? задача же вообще изи то? ну, если ваша проблема именно в сортировке отображения блоков, то проще всего сделать используя grid-layout

Answer (score 1, accepted):

используй гриды. Вот тут пример https://codepen.io/julesforrest/pen/xLBbVb

```
.grid {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: 1fr 1fr 1fr 1fr;
}

.item-a {
  grid-column-start: 1;
  grid-column-end: 5;
}

.item-b {
  grid-column-start: 1;
  grid-column-end: span 4;
}
```

Comment: Флоаты мне чем-то показались легче гридов. Однако сейчас попробовал, и результат превзошёл все ожидания )

Comment: флоаты и флексы проще, но они многое не могут.